# Where to add getName() method in an object oriented class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a app that uses 3 separate classes to pass information through to the main activity, that passes information into an array that will then list off states when the first letter is typed.   The coding seems to be all there and in theory working like it should... however when trying to type a letter I get this instead of showing any states list:

[Click here to show what happens on the emulator, weird error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Osr.jpg)

I'm pretty sure I need to add a getName() method somewhere in the states class from what I've seen in trying to solve my problem and then call it into the main-activity, but I'm struggling as to where or how, but I'm not overly experienced in multi classes, and def not used to the getName() method. Or if someone has another suggestion on how to pass just the name instead of the whole state class (which i think is what is causing the issue) I'd love to hear/see it!

Code as follows:

main.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Look for States below"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search States"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:hint="Type a Letter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

City.java

```js
public class City {
    String name;
    int population;

    public City () {
}

public City(int pop, String city_name){

     name = city_name;
     population = pop;

}

public String getName(){

    return name;

}


}
```

capital.java

```js
public class Capital extends City {

    public Capital(int pop,String name){
        super(pop, name);
    }
}
```

state.java

```js
public class State {

    City capital;
    String name;

    public State (String stateName, String capitalName, int pop){

        name = stateName;

        Capital cap = new Capital(pop, capitalName);
        capital = cap;
    }


    public boolean startWith(char s)   {
        return s == name.charAt(0);

    }



}
```

and lastly my mainactivity.java

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button stateLook;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    EditText searchBox;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        stateLook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);

    };



    public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayList states = new ArrayList();
        states.add(new State("Alabama", "Montgomery", 205764));
        states.add(new State("Alaska", "Juneau", 31275));
        states.add(new State("Arizona", "Phoenix", 1445632));
        states.add(new State("Arkansas", "Little Rock", 193524));
        states.add(new State("California", "Sacramento", 466488));
        states.add(new State("Colorado", "Denver", 600158));
        states.add(new State("Connecticut", "Hartford", 124775));
        states.add(new State("Delaware", "Dover", 36047));
        states.add(new State("Florida", "Tallahassee", 181412));
        states.add(new State("Georgia", "Atlanta", 420003));
        states.add(new State("Hawaii", "Honolulu", 337256));
        states.add(new State("Idaho", "Boise", 205671));
        states.add(new State("Illinois", "Springfield", 116250));
        states.add(new State("India", "Indianapolis", 829718));
        states.add(new State("Iowa", "Des Moines", 203433));
        states.add(new State("Kansas", "Topeka", 127473));




        char s;
        s = searchBox.getText().charAt(0);
        ArrayList stateArray = new ArrayList();
        if (searchBox.getText().length() == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {

                State state = (State) states.get(i);

                ///char s1 = state.charAt(0);

                if (state.startWith(s)) {
                    stateArray.add(state);
                }
            }
        }




       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateArray);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);




    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView myText = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Selected "+ myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are seeing is from the `toString` method.  Override this in you class to produce the output you want.

or change

```
if (state.startWith(s)) {
   stateArray.add(state.getName ());  // create getName method in State (like) getName in Cuty
}
```

Comment: I would upvote you but I don't have the votes to do so, so once I the rep It'll go through (so it told me)